# Can I activate Dawn of Hope's ability twice while only paying its mana cost once?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So, let's say that I have a [Dawn of Hope](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDawn%20of%20Hope%5d) out. I have 2 [Healer's Hawk](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHealer%27s%5d%2b%5bHawk%5d)s that attack on the same turn. I pay 2 mana to draw a card for the lifelink from the 1st healer's hawk. Do I need to spend another 2 mana if I want to draw another card or do I just draw another card automatically since there were 2 lifelink events in that turn?

Comment: To be overly (and necessarily) precise: You don't activate Dawn of Hope's ability, it triggers by itself. Whenever you gain life, it triggers the enchantment, then you may choose to pay 2 generic mana in order to draw a card. Activated abilities have usually a cost and an effect, separated by a colon. If Dawn of Hope was an activated ability, it would read something like this: "Pay 2 generic mana: Draw a card. Activate this ability whenever you gain life, and only once each time you gain life"

Answer (score 5):

As you stated, there are two lifelink events, both setting up an *independent* instance of Dawn of Hope's trigger. In order to draw two cards, you have to spend 4 mana; the second trigger doesn't 'remember' you've paid already for the first trigger.

Comment: Just a small nitpick here, but it's actually generic mana, not colorless. Colorless mana is represented by a gray diamond symbol, while generic is represented by a number (and any color of mana can be used for generic mana costs, not just colorless).

Comment: Heh, I'm old enough to remember the original printing of [Ancient Tomb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4636) ...

Comment: @Glorfindel Colorless mana is something you can have in your mana pool. Generic mana is part of the cost of many spells and abilities. I think that's how it's always been.

Comment: (They may have, at times, used the generic mana _symbol_ when they meant colorless mana, but I have yet to see them mix up the _names_ of the two concepts. Note that even in your Ancient Tomb, they clearly could've used a grey circle with a 2 in it, but they chose not to. Even then, apparently, colorless and genetic were clearly seen as two distinct things by the design team.)

Comment: Yeah, let's just remove the terminology from this Q&A since it's not really relevant :)

Comment: @Arthur The FtV lands printing of [Ancient Tomb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=288994) used that grey circle with a two in it. At the time of the original print, they hadn't started to use that method to denote colorless mana creation in any cards. It's also worth noting that the two ideas were used pretty much interchangeably until OGW created cards that required mana to be colorless and not generic.

Comment: It is not accurate to say that the ideas of generic and colorless mana were used interchangeably before OGW. The same symbols were used to represent each, but they were definitely separate things.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that it says "If you do", not "If you did". It is not checking whether you have, at some point, paid 2 generic mana. It's checking whether you paying 2 happened for that trigger. Every time you gain life, Dawn of Hope puts a "You may pay 2. If you do, draw a card." on the stack. Each time such a trigger resolves, you either pay 2 and draw a card, or nothing happens.  If, theoretically, there were a card that says "Every time you gain life, you may pay 2. If you have paid 2 this turn, draw a card." or "You may pay 2. If you do, for the rest of the turn, draw a card every time you gain life." then you could pay just 2 to draw two cards. But this card is worded as "Each time you gain life, you may pay 2 to draw a card", not "You may pay 2 to draw a card every time you gain life".

Comment: Thanks everyone, that definitely cleared that up for me!